# How to recover imported functions in IPython process

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, pyc

I have a function called `simulate` imported with `from utils.compute_CV_threshold import simulate, compute_OOS_pnl_by_CV, compute_SIMS`.

However, I accidentally deleted `utils` folder, hence `inspect` cannot retrieve source codes in this case. .

Is there anyway to get the source code of `simulate` by decompiling the byte codes in jupyter notebook?

Thanks